# How to we migrate numeric data types with length to spark sql supported data type

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-sql-database, databricks-sql

we are migrating azure sql views to delta format files to saved as table and on top of that, we are creating the unity catalog, if numeric(12,0) is in sql server, we have to similar kind of data type and length required in spark sql.

if we use numeric data type in spark sql bydefault taking decimal(12,0), please help us, how to manage to spark sql side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try below 2 options :

```
cast(columnName As Int)
```

**OR**

```
split(columnName,"\\.")(0)
```

Comment: if we give the int by default take fixed length, we can't set as we expected or like 12,0 ..etc

Comment: did you try both options ?